# Mac App Store Sandbox - installing user scripts?

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store

My OSX App is sandboxed, and I would like to give users an option to install some optional bash scripts into ~/Library/Application Scripts/

Apple review doesn't like the method i have used:
opening a seperate window with an option to drag&drop into the correct location.

I referred to this article, and thought it would be ok for the MAS:
https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/sandbox-scripting/

Does anyone have any tips about how to go about this?
I seem to remember some apps providing a download of external scripts, but if Apple doesn't like the drag&drop, why would they prefer an option to download in the UI instead?

Or would I need to direct users to my site after purchase, and tell them why they have this convoluted install method, and then direct them to download & install the extra scripts?

Any pointers anyone could offer would be great.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a button directing users to a webpage. On the page were the required scripts, and a description of where to put them.
It's less than ideal, and I can't see how this is a more secure option.... but it does work, and allowed my app through the review process.
:(